# having trouble with pyaudio

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pyaudio

'No module named 'pyaudio' I have it installed on my terminal and I just updated pyaudio and python and it still won't work. Will pyaudio just not work on newer versions? Do I have to back to older versions?

Comment: you mean even after using `pip install PyAudio` it still doesn't work?

Comment: Please, provide more details. Can you show the output of `pip install PyAudio` as @HjSin suggests? Do you see it on `pip list`? What is your python code? Do you use the same python environment?

Comment: try `which pip` and `which python` in your terminal - make sure you're installing it into the correct environment

Comment: @Hj Sin yes I tried in my computer terminal and in VScode

Answer (score 0):

> [whl extentions](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

Download appropriate pyaudio extension. Open your command prompt wherever you downloaded the file.

Do not forget to add .whl to your pip command. Your command should look like
pip install filename.whl